# Php Array Splice does not compare size

Tags: php, compare, detect, array-push, array-splice

The array should push new item in array instead of increasing quantity when size is different, but it increases quantity and overwrites size of the previous item. Has anybody a constructive solution please?

```
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$size = $_POST['size'];
$wasFound = false;
$i = 0;
// If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
    // RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(0 => array("item_id" => $pid, "size" => $size, "quantity" => 1));
} else {
    // RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
          $i++;
          while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
              if ($key == "item_id"&&"size" && $value == $pid&&$size) {
                  // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                  array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $pid, "size" => $size, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                  $wasFound = true;
              } // close if condition
          } // close while loop
       } // close foreach loop
       if ($wasFound == false) {
           array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid,"size" => $size, "quantity" => 1));
       }
}
header("location: cart.php"); 
exit();
}
```